# I want to compare multiple strings using the strcmp and display the output after it succesfully verify both inputs

Tags: c, authentication

```
typedef struct uLogin
{
    char user1,user2,user3,user4;
} uLogin;


void loginUser() {

    uLogin x1;
    int i, m, n;

    char pass_list[20] = "12345678",name[10],pass[10];
    x1.user1 = "DSET2G1";
    x1.user2 = "DSET2G2";
    x1.user3 = "DSET2G3";
    x1.user4 = "DSET2G4";

    printf("\nEnter username: ");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("\nEnter Password :");
    scanf("%s",&pass);
    fflush(stdout);

    m = (strcmp(name,x1.user1)==0 && strcmp(name,x1.user2)==0 && strcmp(name,x1.user3)==0 && strcmp(name,x1.user4)==0);
    n = strcmp(pass,pass_list);

    if(m == 0 && n == 0)
    {
        system("CLS");
        printf("Hello");
    }
    else
    {
        system("CLS");
        printf("Bye");
    }



}
```

Im trying to get this code to work but I dont understand why does the code terminates after typing the username and password for this simple user login page. Any ideas and can someone explain whats wrong? Sorry for bad english

Comment: `x1.user1` is of type `char`.  Surely the compiler warns you about the initialization `x1.user1 =  "DSET2G1";`

Comment: `scanf("%s",&name);` is no better than `gets`.  That should be `scanf("%9s", name);` and make sure you check the return value.   Since name is not initialized you will get undefined behavior if `scanf` does not return 1 and you attempt to read `name`.

Comment: Don't even try to run your program while the compiler shows tons of warnings. I can hardly believe `strcmp(name,x1.user1)` doesn't cause some warning for passing an integer while a pointer is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first thing that you should notice is that the member of your struct are just `char`, and you are trying to assign a full string to them. You should see that from the compiler warnings.

However, I saw several issues in your code and I provide here an improved version which should be more safe/stable in terms of memory corruption. Note that I used a fixed memory length for the strings, you can upgrade the code with dynamic memory but only if you know what you are doing.

See comments in the code for the description of the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_USERNAME_LEN 256

// Change 1 -> Declare the member of the struct as pointers to char
typedef struct uLogin
{
    char* user1,*user2,*user3,*user4;
} uLogin;


void loginUser() {

    uLogin x1;
    int i, m, n;

    char pass_list[MAX_USERNAME_LEN] = "12345678";
    char name[MAX_USERNAME_LEN],pass[MAX_USERNAME_LEN];
    
    // Change 2: declare the stings as local variables, 
    //then assign the address of them to the struct members
    
    char s1[MAX_USERNAME_LEN] = "DSET2G1";
    char s2[MAX_USERNAME_LEN] = "DSET2G2";
    char s3[MAX_USERNAME_LEN] = "DSET2G3";
    char s4[MAX_USERNAME_LEN] = "DSET2G4";
    
    x1.user1 = s1;
    x1.user2 = s2;
    x1.user3 = s3;
    x1.user4 = s4;
    
    // Change 3: use a safer way to read the input 
    // I leave the error handling to you
    char line[MAX_USERNAME_LEN];
    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        if (1 == sscanf(line, "%s", (char*)&name)) {
            /* i can be safely used */
        }
    }

    if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        if (1 == sscanf(line, "%s", (char*)&pass)) {
            /* i can be safely used */
        }
    }
    
    // Change 4 - Use strncmp to compare exactly MAX_USERNAME_LEN bytes
    // Change 5 - Fix the logic to have at least one combination right
    int ret1 = strncmp(name,x1.user1,MAX_USERNAME_LEN)==0;
    int ret2 = strncmp(name,x1.user2,MAX_USERNAME_LEN)==0;
    int ret3 = strncmp(name,x1.user3,MAX_USERNAME_LEN)==0;
    int ret4 = strncmp(name,x1.user4,MAX_USERNAME_LEN)==0;


    m = ret1 || ret2 || ret3 || ret4;
         
    n = strncmp(pass,pass_list,MAX_USERNAME_LEN) == 0;

    printf("%d %d %d %d -> m %d n %d \n",ret1,ret2,ret3,ret4,m,n);

    if(m == 1 && n == 1)
    {
        //system("CLS");
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
    else
    {
        //system("CLS");
        printf("Bye\n");
    }



}

int main(){
    while(1)
    loginUser();
 
}
```

Some output samples:

```
DSET2G1
12345678
1 0 0 0 -> m 1 n 1 
Hello

DSET2G1
fdgsfhjsdf
1 0 0 0 -> m 1 n 0 
Bye

DSET2G6
12345678
0 0 0 0 -> m 0 n 1 
Bye
```

Comment: `x1.user1 = (char*)&s1;`You should better use `= s1`. That already has correct type and there is no need to cast. Similar for `scanf`: ` (char*)&name` Better use `name`. An array already decays to a pointer to first element. Adding `&` makes it a pointer to the array instead which is not the type you want.

Comment: Why do you change all array sizes? `pass[MAX_USERNAME_LEN]` Using user name length for password does not really make sense. Instead of using `strncmp` it would make more sense to limit the input accordingly: `"%9s"` instead of `"%s"`. If you need `strncmp` because the input string could be longer than array size, then it is already way too late to check.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks a lot for your inputs! I agree with what you said and I will edit the answer.

Comment: However I changed the array sizes for simplicity, I believe OP can figure out themselves the correct length. This is not a ready to copy-paste code, but a step into the right direction for OP.

Comment: Im a little bit confused on the input part where I enter the username and password because Im a beginner can you explain it? or any alternative ways?

Comment: @renlovescookies sure. The first part uses `fgets` which has the option the specify a maximum amount of characters to read. If you put this amount as the max size of the destination buffer, you are sure you can't overflow. After that your input is in a temp buffer, and you use `sscanf` which reads from that buffer instead of the standard input.